# jax-rs response entity is not the xmlroot but is an element

Tags: jaxb, jax-rs

I have a JAX-RS response method which

```java
@Produces('application/xml', 'application/json')
```

I also have a JAX-B entity which produces this:

```xml
<person>
    <name>joe</name>
    <address>
        <street>123 home</street>
    </address>
<person>
```

for this call `/person/Joe`

I would like to respond with `/person/joe/address`

and return

```
  <address>
       <street>123 home</street>
  </address>
```

using JAX-RS/Jersey  I get an error:

> no marshaller for type Address.class when mime type is application/XML

This is happening because the address object is not annotated as `@XMLRootElement`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have written a simple provider to handle this scenario and it appears to work just as I expected. it will wrap the xmlType in an jaxbelement so that it can be marshalled.

```java
/**
 * by default we are unable to write an {@link XmlType} object as xml it must be
 * an {@link XmlRootElement} based object this class will wrap {@link XmlType}
 * with {@link JAXBElement} and marshall them
 * 
 * @author shaun
 * 
 */
@Provider
@Consumes({ "application/xml", "text/xml" })
public class XMLTypeWriter extends AbstractRootElementProvider {

    private static final Logger logger = LoggerFactory.getLogger(XMLTypeWriter.class);

    public XMLTypeWriter(@Context Providers ps) {
        super(ps, MediaType.APPLICATION_XML_TYPE);
    }

    @Override
    protected boolean isSupported(MediaType m) {
        return (m.equals(MediaType.APPLICATION_XML_TYPE) || m.equals(MediaType.TEXT_XML_TYPE));
    }

    @Override
    public boolean isReadable(Class<?> type, Type genericType, Annotation[] annotations, MediaType mediaType) {
        // There is already a xmltype reader defined.
        return false;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean isWriteable(Class<?> type, Type genericType, Annotation[] annotations, MediaType mediaType) {
        return type.isAnnotationPresent(XmlType.class) && isSupported(mediaType);
    }

    @Override
    protected void writeTo(Object t, MediaType mediaType, Charset c, Marshaller m, OutputStream entityStream) throws JAXBException {

        // need to get the type name from the annotation
        XmlType xt = t.getClass().getAnnotation(XmlType.class);
        JAXBElement p = null;
        if (xt != null) {
            String name = xt.name();
            p = new JAXBElement(QName.valueOf(name), t.getClass(), t);
        }
        super.writeTo(p, mediaType, c, m, entityStream);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You could annotate the `Address` class with `@XmlRootElement` or wrap it in an instance of `JAXBElement`.

```java
new JAXBElement<Address>(
    new QName("address"), 
    Address.class, 
    address);
```

Comment: the classes are generated from an xsd so I cannot put the XmlRootElement annotation on the Address.  I have also tried wrapping the Class with a JAXBElement as you mentioned however that breaks the json response to where it will marshall the JAXBElement to a json element.

Comment: i am using jackson on jaxb entities via jersey